# How to convert multi python tkinter file to .exe file

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I create

> main tkinter (GUI_main = Tk()) (main.py)

and import the

> second GUI (from secondguiprogram import secondgui_GUI) (GUI_2 = Toplevel()) (secondguiprogram.py)

when I test my program with Sublime Text it work properly but I try to create exe file by doing follow this code

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py
```

the program not working proper following the program order
example: when I click create pdf (from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas) command in second window and close pdf program, the main window is appear on top instead of the second window.

Comment: I think you have to copy `secondguiprogram.py` to the location of your exe

Comment: @CoolCloud follow your recommendation, the results remain the same.

Comment: Then remove the `--noconsole` and try again and edit the question with the error that comes.

Comment: without "--noconsole" It works without any errors, and the program is running correctly in program order. Do you have any idea about this? @CoolCloud

Comment: It is probably due to some problem from `reportlab`